# Determining resident status when filling W-4 form in

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, form-w-4

I just arrived to US because of a post-doc position in an IT company, under a J-1 visa (research scholar). I have been told by the company to fill W-4 form in. But, it seems that W-4 form must be filled in differently depending on my current status (resident alien or nonresident alien).

The rules to decide which is my status are here: http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html

Basically, it seems I need to pass the *substantial presence test* (see previous link) to determine whether I am a resident alien or not (I cannot meet the other criteria: *green card test*). At this moment, I definitely do not meet the substantial presence test, since I just arrived to US.

I understand, however, that I will need to file my first tax return on April 2014 (since I am going to start working next week, and my fiscal year will end on December 2013). At that moment, I believe I *will* actually meet the substantial presence test.

So, my question is: should I decide if I am a resident alien or not based on the date that I start working, or based on the date I will file my tax return?

Answer (score 4):

> At that moment, I will actually meet the substantial presence test.

No, actually, you will not. Days present in J status are excluded from the substantial presence count.

See down the page you linked to, it starts with "**Students**".

> Form 8843.   If you exclude days of presence in the United States
>   because you fall into any of the following categories, you must file a
>   fully completed Form 8843.
>
> - You were unable to leave the United States as planned because of a medical condition or problem.
> - You were temporarily in the United States as a teacher or trainee on a “J” or “Q” visa.
> - You were temporarily in the United States as a student on an “F,” “J,” “M,” or “Q” visa.
> - You were a professional athlete competing in a charitable sports event.

Comment: I already saw that part, and I thought that only applied to J-1 under the "student" program. In my case, I am under the "research scholar" program. According to http://j1visa.state.gov/programs, those are different programs. So, I believe the days I expend in US will be counted for the presence test. Of course, I may be wrong, though.

Comment: @betabandido: littleadv is correct. J-1 people who are not students fall under "teachers and trainees" http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_publink1000222140 . However, there are limits on how long you can be considered an exempt individual. For students, it's no more than 5 years. For teachers and trainees, it's no more than 2 years in a 7 year period.

Comment: @user102008 It is true that publication 519 only lists students, teachers, and trainees. But in the [J-1 visa program list](http://j1visa.state.gov/programs), it is possible to find those three programs (student, teacher and trainee), plus some other programs such as: specialist, professor, research scholar, etc. I do not think that specialists fall into either teacher or trainee programs. So, my guess is that J-1 programs not listed in publication 519 are not affected by the exemption rule. Am I correct there?

Comment: @littleadv There is a specific *intern* program in J-1 visa, which seems to be different from teacher or trainee. In my case, I am not an intern, but a research scholar. None of those classes are listed in publication 519. The problem is that pub. 519 does not mention what happens with other J-1 programs. So I am not sure what applies to my case.

Comment: @littleadv I am not saying that it is better for me. I just want to be sure not to make a mistake when filling W-4 form in. In which part of publication 519 does it say that research scholars are exempt for 2 years? I could not find that.

Comment: @betabandido: Publication 519 says "A teacher or trainee is an individual, other than a student, who is temporarily in the United States under a “J” or “Q” visa and substantially complies with the requirements of that visa." So under that definition, you are under "teachers and trainees"

Comment: @user102008 Indeed, that subtle part is what classifies any non-student holder of a J-1 visa into a teacher or trainee. Legal writing is not always clear, and I guess I would just prefer if the text explicitly stated that all other J-1 programs (such as au-pair, intern, research scholar, etc.) are classified as teacher/trainee. Thanks for your comment.